# Как создать dockerfile для Core net?

Tags: asp.net-core, docker

Как создать dockerfile для Core net?

Answer (score 0):

```
ARG REPO=microsoft/dotnet
FROM $REPO:3.0-runtime-deps-stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install ASP.NET Core
ENV ASPNETCORE_VERSION 3.0.0-preview-19075-0444

RUN curl -SL --output aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$ASPNETCORE_VERSION/aspnetcore-runtime-$ASPNETCORE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='cfcb904b736cf1b477c6c63b30c117c07ea4179e695becea249745c17f5b6f81354305216b4dafbc7b52a17417bf123596dc01b1a9572e9340bda13a086a6ab7' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf aspnetcore.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

Взято из https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker